# Bias of overlap sampling

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, time-series, descriptive-statistics

Say I have a series $x_1, ...., x_N$ independently drawn from $Normal(0,1)$

Say I create sub-samples

$y_1 = x_1+..x_n$,
$y_2 = x_2+..x_{n+1}$,

$y_m = x_{N-n}+..x_N$,

I was expecting $std(\{y\}) = \sqrt(n) std(\{x\})$

where $std(\{y\})$ is the standard deviation of the set $y_1,...,y_m$.
where $std(\{x\})$ is the standard deviation of the set $x_1,...,x_N$.

But this is not the case. 
Because of overlap sampling  $std(\{y\}) < \sqrt(n) std(\{x\})$

If I performed non-overlapped sampling like

$z_1 = x_1+..x_n$,
$z_2 = x_{n+1}+..x_{2n}$,

$z_p = x_{pn+1}+..x_N$,

then I would get $std(\{z\}) = \sqrt(n) std(\{x\})$

here $std(\{z\})$ is the standard deviation of the set $z_1,...,z_p$.

My question: is there a theoritical estimate of the amount of bias for normal distribution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you mean $y_m=x_{N-n+1}+\cdots+x_N$? (Where, by the way, $m=N-n+1$.)

Comment: the y's are overlapped. if i choose say $y_{10}$ and $y_9$ then except $x_9$ and $x_{9+n}$ rest of the elements are common in the summation. whereas the z's are sum of completely disjoint sets.

Comment: Yes, that was clear from your problem statement. I don't see how it relates to my comment. I doubt that you intended $y_1$ and $y_2$ to have $n$ summands each but $y_m$ to have $n+1$?